# Trouble with multiplayer on Minecraft PE 0.12.1

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friends and I wanted to play Minecraft Pocket Edition together when the new update came out, but my iPad can't find any worlds on other devices and none of my worlds are appearing on their devices either. However, I'm the only one who it doesn't work for. We all have the same version of the game, we're connected to the same wifi, and I've got local server multiplayer turned on. If anyone knows what the problem is and could help me, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this issue as well. What I have found seems to work, make certain the host device world setting is shared. Then enter and wait in the setting screen. At this point the other devices should see the host device world (they may have to close and reopen the world selection screen). If this does not work on first try then close and kill the app on hosting device and reopen it. By close and kill you need to double tap the home button and then swipe the app off screen to kill it.

I play all the time with my son and this issue happens a lot. Using this technique has worked almost 100% of time. If you are  paranoid you can also flip the WiFi option off and back on again while waiting in the setting screen.

Comment: We seem to have exactly the same problem. What exactly do you mean with "make certain the host device world setting is shared"?

Comment: Quitting and restarting the app worked for me; you enabled 2 very happy 9-year-olds.

Comment: @DanielWidh there is an option to make the world shared. It's under options->game->local server multiplayer. If that isn't on the world won't show up for anybody.

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot see what the issue may be. Based on what you have said, you seem to have reviewed most of the available options. This is unlikely the problem, however you could attempt to see whether or not you are trying to use duplicate usernames.

Answer (score -1):

Can't punch someone? Its because you effect your self weakness once.
All you have to do is effect our self with strength potion because thats your only choice. If it strength effect is gone then you can't punch someone again. So you need to do it all over again.